# How do I register a Wine App as an "Other Application" in 11.10?

Tags: wine

I was previously able to use a script to open .psd files with Photoshop CS2 and pass the file name to the application. In 11.10 I can't seem to easily add my own apps to the "Other Application list that would be available from nautilus. I've tried under Unity and under my default gnome shell session.

Comment: Me too, only in my case it's dosbox :(

Comment: Have you tried with [.desktop](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html) file? Check the "Mimetypes" keys also

Comment: I created a .desktop file, but it doesn't show up in the open with dialog. How does one manipulate the Mimetypes keys in 11.10?

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this, and it turns out that the trick with having something show up as an "Other Application" lies in having %f on the executable line of the .desktop file. Here is my "corrected" .desktop file for the the Wine program I'm running PDFEdit (I have shell scripts set up in my .Wine folder that are being referred to.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Lauch with PDFEDit
Comment=Launch with PDF Edit
Exec=/home/kschiff/.wine/Foxit %f
Icon=/home/kschiff/Pictures/Ubuntu Wallpaper and Icons/icons/Foxit.png
Terminal=0
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Network;Application;
```